# PhpStorm local debugging stopped working - Do you see problem in setup?

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I used to have PhpStorm working brilliantly on my computer. No browser extensions. I could put breakpoints anywhere, go to some URL in browser, hit enter and then I would automatically be taken to breakpoint in given file. Files in project would open up automatically as I stepped through code.

Now, it is a total mess.

First here is my Xdebug info in the xdebug.ini (I don't specify anything Xdebug related in the php.ini):

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
```

If I run `php -v` I get

```
PHP 7.0.15 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2017 10:30:54) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.15, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
iMac:xdebug-2.7.2 $
```

`phpinfo()` shows corresponding values set based on my .ini.

In PhpStorm I have PHP CLI set to 7.0, it is showing Xdebug 2.7.2.

[image]

[image]

Curious about that "Can't load xdebug" message, but `php -v` doesn't show same message. At first I had zend_extension defined in both php.ini and the xdebug .ini and would see that message when doing `php -v` but after removing from `php.ini` the message went away from `php -v`.

I have no idea if I need to do anything under Debug settings in Build, Deployment, but here is what is there by default:

[image]

Also, I have my project set to sync with a remote server but for debugging I don't want to use path mappings. That is how I had it before and PhpStorm messages about debug session ending and no path mappings found was never a problem.

Here is my `Run->Config`

[image]

In the past, I didn't worry about a start URL. No matter what URL I entered in browser it triggered debugging.

[image]

And here is what I have tried regarding path mappings:

[image]

I did that to see if it would fix things, but no.

My gut feeling says it is either a problem with Xdebug settings, my run->config, or the fact that I am using a virtual host and somewhere there is a localhost entry causing a problem.

So I am at a loss. If I select `Listen for incoming...` and go to URL, the focus does not go to PhpStorm with current breakpoint. I see in browser that things stopped and I go to PhpStorm and see that debug was triggered. But the second I hit step over or step into the debugging just ends.

Anything glaringly wrong with what I am doing?

Edit: Here is what I see in the xdebug log:

```
[89603] W: Creating socket for 'dev.courses.com:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[89603] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[89603] Log closed at 2019-10-21 10:42:37
[89603]
[89603] Log opened at 2019-10-21 10:42:37
[89603] I: Connecting to configured address/port: dev.courses.com:9000.
[89603] W: Creating socket for 'dev.courses.com:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
[89603] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[89603] Log closed at 2019-10-21 10:42:37
```

Not sure the specifics of the error... Maybe this hints at something? The question I have is where in the config do I specify localhost vs my virtual host alias? Maybe that is what is messing things up?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what Xdebug is trying to do by using the `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` setting. This log will indicate which connection attempts are being made, and why they succeed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this turned out to be an `xdebug` issue, though not obvious at first.

Originally I didn't think to check the PHPStorm log. But the PHPStorm log showed

```
Argument for @NotNull parameter 'remoteFileUrl' of com/jetbrains/php/debug/xdebug/debugger/XdebugDriver.onBreak must not be null
```

Searching above error took me to

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001498520-xdebug-works-only-with-first-line

Turns out my version of PHPStorm is known to not work with `xdebug` 2.7 so I downgraded to 2.6.1 and all is well :-)

thanks,
Brian